# How to implement QThread in Cython, PyQT GUI ?

Tags: python, pyqt, cython, qthread

I have defined 2 classes, one a cython class defined as `AndorCameraSDK` and a python class `AndorCameraGUI`. `AndorCameraGUI` consists of a GUI created using PyQt and `AndorCameraSDK` consists of camera functionalities.
In class `AndorCameraSDK`, there exist a function `LiveAcquisition` which consists of acquiring images and displaying them after acquisition.I need to make acquiring and displaying on 2 seperate threads.

When I looked up at QThreads examples, it's clearly mentioned to define the threading function within `run()` inside a Threading class.

```
class YourThreadName(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()
    def run(self):
        #your logic here
```

`LiveAcquisition` code :

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def LiveAquisition(self,nframes):
    cdef:
        int available
        AT_64 sizeInBytes
        AT_64 aoiStride
        AT_WC string[20]
        AT_WC string1[20]
        AT_WC string2[20]
        AT_WC string3[20]
        unsigned int timeOut
        unsigned char * pBuf
        unsigned char * _puc_image
        int BufSize
        unsigned int i
        np.npy_intp dims[2]
        np.npy_intp strides[2]
        np.dtype dtype = np.dtype('<H')

    copy2WCStr("Acquisition Start",string)
    response_code = AT_Command(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle, string)

    copy2WCStr("ImageSizeBytes",string1)
    AT_GetInt(<AT_H> self.cameraHandle, string1, &sizeInBytes)

    copy2WCStr("AOIStride",string1)
    AT_GetInt(<AT_H> self.cameraHandle, string1, &aoiStride)


    dims[0] = self.aoiWidth/self.hbin
    dims[1] = self.aoiHeight/self.vbin

    strides[0] = 2
    strides[1] = aoiStride

    image = np.zeros(((self.aoiWidth-self.AOILeft)/self.hbin, (self.aoiHeight-self.AOITop)/self.vbin), dtype=np.uint16)
    image = np.zeros(((self.aoiWidth)/self.hbin, (self.aoiHeight)/self.vbin), dtype=np.uint16)


    self.i = 0
    self.nframes = nframes
    start = time.time()
    def update():
        pBuf = <unsigned char *>calloc(sizeInBytes, sizeof(unsigned char))
        AT_QueueBuffer(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle, pBuf, sizeInBytes)

        print "Frame number is :",
        print self.i



        timeOut = <unsigned int>(3 * self.exposureTime * 1000)
        response_code = AT_WaitBuffer(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle, &pBuf, &BufSize, timeOut)

        Py_INCREF(dtype)

        image = PyArray_NewFromDescr(<PyTypeObject *> np.ndarray, np.dtype('<H'), 2,dims, strides,pBuf, np.NPY_C_CONTIGUOUS,None) # reshaping into 2D array
        self.master.LivePlot(image) #display function
        free(pBuf)
        self.i = self.i+1
        if self.i <self.nframes:
            timer = QtCore.QTimer()
            timer.singleShot(0,update)
        if self.i == (self.nframes):
            copy2WCStr("AcquisitionStop",string3)
            AT_Command(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle, string3)
            AT_Flush(<AT_H>self.cameraHandle)
            stop = time.time()
            print "Time:",
            print stop-start
    update()
```

1. If a separate class for threading has to be defined how do I separate image acquisition and display as image acquisition part of code consists of camera initialization previously defined in the `AndorCameraSDK` class.
2. Display function `LivePlot` is defined in a python file using PyQt.

Could anyone please help me out here ?